# Submit form after search button is pressed using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span id="search_concept">Filter</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul   class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                  <li><a href="#Electronics">electronics</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#Movies">movies</a></li>

                                  <li class="divider"></li>
                                  <li><a href="#all">All</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    <form method="POST" name="form" action="#">

                                <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" id="query" placeholder="Search term...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default"  type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </span>

                    </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
```

**ISSUE**
Everytime I press Go button; I redirect to same page; which I want however by drop down acts funky; like it doesn't replace the 'filter' button with appropriate choosen filter inside dropdown-menu when after the form gets submitted. Here's the code for that. However before I press go button it works as expected. What could be happening?

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(e){
              $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
              var concept = $(this).text();
              $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
              $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
              });
            });

  </script>
```

JS FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/0e37tvyx/

Comment: Make a jsfiddle

Comment: What is the filter dropdown supposed to do?
What is the text in the input box supposed with the filter dropdown?

What is supposed to happen after search is complete?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in this. Your fiddle code works fine for all UI change operations. But because your form supports `POST` method, all your form parameters are submitted as `POST` request. You have three possible options (may be more than that too) to preserve the state of last chosen filters:

1. Use ajax request instead of form submit with entire page refresh. In this way you will have to add content from server response in your page; that is search results.
2. If your content is generating dynamically. I mean to say you are using `PHP` / `JSP` / `ASP` / `Any Other Templating Library`, you can use that, to update the HTML code based upon the search request, i.e. `search_param` request param.
3. The other way is use cookies. When user changes the option in front end preserve the filter option `search_param` in cookies. And on `ready` state of document; read those saved cookies if exists or fallback to default option `all` if not already stored in cookies.

Check out the fiddle for cookie based implementation. Not that I have added cookies plugin of jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/ksbora/3w6k171f/2

Note: `Cookies` has size limitations too and cross site origination restrictions. So, be careful which option you choose.